# How to create a dotenv file using Github Actions in the Deploy steps?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I'm learning CI CD to deploy REST API to VPS using Github Actions.

I am confused about how to make a dotenv file so that it is on the VPS server using Github Actions, because this REST API requires a Jsonwebtoken key and I have to insert it in the .env file. I've tried several ways but nothing works.

If you have the answer, please modify my .yml file below and include your answer so I can understand it clearly.

I really appreciate any answer.

```
name: Node.js CICD

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: create env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=${{ secrets.JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }} >> .env

      - name: install and test
        run: |
          npm i
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test
        env:
          CI: true

  deploy:
    needs: [test]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: deploy with SSH
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            cd ~/apps/routeros-api
            git pull origin master
            npm i --production
            pm2 restart routeros-api
```

Comment: In which job do you need the .env file and where it should be located? What is the error?

Comment: job deploy, the .env file was not successfully created on the VPS server. I have tried to move the 'create .env' step in the job test but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? if you need the file in the job deploy, you need to create the .env file there. You can't share files between jobs.